# simple onclick event not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I've got quite a simple set up with html, css, and javascipt.
When the user clicks on one of the many divs there are, it should either appear or disappear, as well as setting a hidden form field to "1" or "0".

First, the css:

```
div.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
div.shown{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

javascript:

```
function toggle(id){
    if (document.getElementById("h"+id).value=="0"){
        document.getElementById("h"+id).value="1";
        document.getElementById("i"+id).className='shown';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("h"+id).value="0";
        document.getElementById("i"+id).className='hidden';
    }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="foo.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form action="blah blah" > 
    <div class="hidden" id="i0" onclick="toggle(0);" >
      <!--some image -->
      <input type="hidden" id="h0" name="0" value="0" />
    </div>

    <div class="hidden" id="i1" onclick="toggle(1);" >
      <!--some image -->
      <input type="hidden" id="h1" name="1" value="0" />
    </div>

    <!-- etc -->
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know the javascript is properly linked and operational, because when I call the function via chrome's console, it works perfectly and does what I expect. However, when I click this div, it does not work!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divs are hidden initially (`class="hidden"`), so you won't see anything when you run the page and won't be able to click on them. Also you have typos (there is no `onlick` event, yet :-)):

```
onlick="toggle(1);"
```

should probably be:

```
onclick="toggle(1);"
```

Comment: You're dead right. If the div is hidden, although there's still space for it on the page, it doesn't react to user input. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must try to lick your element not click, maybe then it will work. Or change onlick to onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Id's cannot start with a number. That is a specification.

Try it like this:

```
function toggle(id){
    if (document.getElementById(id).value=="0"){
        document.getElementById(id).value="1";
        document.getElementById("i"+id.substr(1)).className='shown';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(id).value="0";
        document.getElementById("i"+id.substr(1)).className='hidden';
    }
}
```

-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="foo.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form action="blah blah" > 
    <div class="hidden" id="i0" onclick="toggle('t0');" >
      <!--some image -->
      <input type="hidden" id="t0" name="0" value="0" />
    </div>

    <div class="hidden" id="i1" onclick="toggle('t1');" >
      <!--some image -->
      <input type="hidden" id="t1" name="1" value="0" />
    </div>

    <!-- etc -->
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is also a typo. onclick.

Comment: My two solutions combined should work. Just copy&paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an event on an hidden element i think and thus it doesn't do anything.